# Which SBC for ROS2?

Tags: ros2, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to use ROS2 Foxy on my Raspberry pi 3 with Ubuntu 20.04 Server but it seems to be difficult to run something..
So I'm thinking to buy another SBC.

Which SBC do you recommend  for ROS2 ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376388/which-sbc-for-ros2-?/) by [Vaneltin](https://answers.ros.org/users/60157/vaneltin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how big is you buget?
can you offer an nvida AGX board?

you may the a board with an i7 or i9

there is not the best board for ros2 you may find the best fitting board for you application.

the factors are cost, energy, size, compute power.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2021-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vaneltin](https://answers.ros.org/users/60157/vaneltin/) on 2021-04-18**:
I'm working on an AMR and I have 200€ of budget.
I think an Raspberry Pi 4 8Go RAM could do the job because I only have a lidar YDLIDAR X4 and motor driver to control.
I've seen the ADlink ROS Cube too but I haven't found where to buy and I think it costs more than 200€.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2021-04-18**:
i thin with this budget you update to an rasberry 4 as you write. the nvidia jetson nano is also good if you plan to do sime ai or computer vision stuff. but it has only 4gig of ram but some cuda cores, und a dual raspi camera interface.